# WebGL2 - Write to texture/buffer at arbitrary position - OpenGL imageStore equivalent

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, textures, webgl2, graphical-programming

I already know how to write to a texture using Framebuffers.

However, for a project I'm doing that requires FFT's, I need at a point to write, in the same shader, into more than one position of the texture/buffer at once.
I have already done this project in OpenGL before, in which I used an imageTexture and "ImageStore" to achieve this effect.

How can I go about achieving this in WebGL?

I can't find anything useful online, since all the things I can find only read from textures or only write to a single point

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to write to multiple separate/scattered points from within a single shader execution in WebGL.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your input, I'll have to find a way around it

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way in WebGL to write to scattered points on a texture.